# Arachnid identification request

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Every so often I come across one of these (presumably) spiders, but haven't been able to find out what species it is.

It is black, ~7mm in length, has a long and narrow body and relatively short legs, and seems to be able to spin threads. I came across it indoors in South-Western Germany in early Summer. The closest match I could find is the [Zebra jumping spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_spider), but "mine" has no stripes. Could it be another species of jumping spider?

I realize the picture quality isn't great, but it's all I have:

[image: The arachnid in question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a zebra jumping spider - but it is in the same family of jumping spiders.
It is a kind of ant-mimic jumping spider. Possible genuses (genera) are: **Synageles**, **Myrmarachne**, **Leptorchestes**, which are present in Europe.

Micaria is another genus in Europe but this does not look like one of those.

There are other similar-looking genera Peckhamia, Sarinda, Synemosyna, but these are mainly found in the Americas and not in Europe.

--

(EDIT) the most observed species in Germany from these genera are (in order):

1. Synageles venator
2. Leptorchestes berolinensis
3. Myrmarachne formicaria

(according to iNaturalist)

Comment: Thanks very much! I can't verify for sure, but Leptorchestes berolinensis looks like a very close match.